# VTT Files not loading in NuxtJS, src returns [object Module]

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, loader

I am trying to get a VTT file to load, but after configuring the loaders, the src is returning [object Module], even if I do require('file').default, it still will not load. Here's my nuxt.config.js build object.

```
build: {
loaders: {
  vue: {
    transformAssetUrls: {
      src: 'src',
      source: 'src',
      track: 'src'
    }
  },
},
extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(vtt)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      esModule: false
    }
  });
}
},
```

Comment: What are VTT files ?

Answer (score 1):

Serve files from `/static` instead import on component.

make a dictionary with your `.vtt` files and add a absolute path of the static folder, if you prefer, create a sub folder called `subtitles` inside static, and make a path on your dict like `subtitles/subtitle_file_name.vtt`

```js
const VideoDictionary = {
  url: 'video_url_here',
  subtitle: 'subtitles/file_name_.vtt'
}
```

```html
<video ...>
  <source :src="VideoDictionary.url" />

  <track 
    :src="VideoDictionary.subtitle" 
    label="English"
    kind="subtitles"
    srclang="en-US"
    default 
  />
</video>
```